# Stringifying a block of text in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

In the code that I am working on has the macro

```
#define STRINGIFY(...) #__VA_ARGS__
```

is defined.

This does have the disadvantage that it ignores newlines.

I would therefore like to define a macro that uses the new `R"literal( ... )literal"` format.

Given that the macro form already exists, I would like to preserve the use of the `STRINGIFY` macro

However given that there are quotes involved, how would you define `STRINGIFY` to use the new string literal format?

Also is there anyway to preserve `#ifdef`s in the `STRINGIFY` macro?

**Edit** I want a define **macro** that will translate into `R"literal(...)literal"` in C++11

**Edit2**
The closest I have been able to get is:

```
#define STRINGIFY1(a) #a 
#define STRINGIFY(str) R STRINGIFY1(lit(str)lit)
```

This puts all the right things in the right place does condense the block into a single line. I am starting to think that macros cannot be used here.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Can you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: You can't (# always outputs old literals), have fun.

Comment: as @n-m says, cant really tell what you wish to achieve at present, so sample input and desired output would be handy:) Just wondering too if there is a specific reason for coding this with macros? as you wont be able to debug them or control them as easily as you would a function.

Comment: This is quite pointless. Raw literals and properly escaped "regular" literals (like the ones generated by `#`) are indistinguishable.

Comment: As @CatPlusPlus said you can't with macros, depending on what it actually is that you are trying to achieve you might have better luck with a constexpr function, which if you really really wanted to call from that STRINGIFY macro for backward compatibility.

Comment: @Wich how would a constexpr function help at all? The only thing it can do is *invent* newlines, because its input will always have all whitespace munged.

Comment: Also, constexpr cannot stringify, period. It's a PP functionality.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: That's not true. You can, for example, widen a literal with a macro, and the same technique should work for rawifying it, as it were. Something like `#define STRINGIFYRAW(...) R ## STRINGIFY(__VA__ARGS__)`.

Comment: @DeadMG no, you can't because there are no delimiters inside the literal (or, maybe there are and then you get a deformed result!). Even if you somehow manage to smuggle safe delimiters in there, all you get is the exact same string that looks slightly different in the preprocessor output that no one will ever look at.

Comment: Why do you want a macro for this? Why do you even have a macro for this? Why would you write `STRINGIFY(1,2,3)` instead of `"1,2,3"`?

Comment: I rephrased the question in terms of problem and not in terms of a potential solution (which was a complete red herring). Feel free to rollback if you think that was not helpful.

Comment: @Martinho - I rolled back the edit. Basically I want the some way of defining a macro that outputs the R"(...)" notation

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly what you asking for, but as **@R. Martinho Fernandes** suggested you can use raw literals:

```
const char *ptr = R"(
text
here
)"
```

Comment: +1: This is the only sane thing to do. It's not clear why a macro is needed and, as such, it's even less clear why one would jump through hoops to make it work as desired when raw string literals already expressly provide this functionality. That's why they were added to the language.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to preserve newlines in the way you want, because the stringise operator explicitly discards them. There's no way to access them in any previous translation phase, and there's no way to recover them in a later one.

> [cpp.stringize]¶2 [...] Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s preprocessing tokens becomes a single space character in the character string literal. White space before the first preprocessing token and after the last preprocessing token comprising the argument is deleted. [...]

You might be able to write a `constexpr` function that builds up a modified string literal by inventing newlines according to some heuristic, but you can never recover the original newlines.